# Can I remove the android-support-v4.jar library?

Tags: android, android-library, android-support-library

When you create a project, it comes with this library added by default:

***android-support-v4.jar***

Can I remove it? What happens if I remove the library? Can the app stop working in some phones?

Answer (score 10):

> Can I remove it?

You can try.

> What happens if I remove that library?

You will not be able to use anything supplied by it, such as the fragments backport, `ViewPager`, etc.

> Can the app stop working in some phones?

You will get build errors first.

Answer (score 4):

You can safely remove it if you don't use APIs not available for your current [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) target.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Eclipse and your project is marked with a red exclamation mark after deleting the android-support-v4 jar, close and restart Eclipse and it should straighten itself out.  (Or you might try just closing and reopening the project.)

Answer (score 1):

It is a support library. You can read about it here:

- *[Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html)*
- *[Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)*

You can safely remove it if you don't use this API.

Answer (score 0):

I just did that. So I get multiple errors in all the projects, like

```
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. 
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
...\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
...\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

This means that the mentioned resources are not available for my projects anymore.

Then I proceeded to add `v7 appcompat`, and I got could not get rid of my errors. So I deleted it, and mistakenly deleted the project from the disk as well, so installed the remnants (I guess) of it, and this did not end well either:

```
[2014-12-07 06:25:16 - android-support-v7-gridlayout] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
[2014-12-07 06:25:16 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
[2014-12-07 06:25:16 - android-support-v7-palette] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
[2014-12-07 06:25:17 - android-support-v7-gridlayout] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
[2014-12-07 06:25:17 - android-support-v7-palette] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
[2014-12-07 06:25:22 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'


...\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\res\values\styles.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
...\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\res\values\styles.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'.
...\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\res\values\styles.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
...\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\res\values\styles.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-12-07 06:25:26 - android-support-v7-mediarouter]
```

**So yeah, DON'T DO IT!**